# Resources for TDD aimed at Python Web Development

Tags: python, tdd, testing

I am a hacker not and not a full-time programmer but am looking to start my own full application development experiment. I apologize if I am missing something easy here. I am looking for recommendations for books, articles, sites, etc for learning more about test driven development specifically compatible with or aimed at Python web application programming. I understand that Python has built-in tools to assist. What would be the best way to learn about these outside of RTFM? I have searched on StackOverflow and found the Kent Beck's and David Astels book on the subject. I have also bookmarked the Wikipedia article as it has many of these types of resources.

Are there any particular ones you would recommend for this language/application?

Comment: What's wrong with http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-unittest.html?  Why is this unacceptable?  Please provide some thing you want that is not provided in the Python documentation, so we know what you're looking for.

Comment: Those questions ask about unit testing in general, not TDD or topics specifically related to TDD web application testing. Good places to start learning how to write tests though, TDD or otherwise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a series of blogs on [TDD in Django](http://blog.cerris.com/category/django-tdd/) that covers some TDD with the [nose testing framework](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/).

There are a lot of free online resources out there for learning about TDD:

- [The c2 wiki article](http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?TestDrivenDevelopment) gives good background on general TDD philosophy.
- [The onlamp article](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2004/12/02/tdd_pyunit.html) is a simple introduction.
- Here's a presentation on [TDD with game development in pygame](http://powertwenty.com/kpd/blog/index.php/python/test_driven_development_in_python) that really helped me understand TDD.

For testing web applications, test first or otherwise, I'd recommend [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) and [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) as tools to use.

Comment: +1 for twill, didn't know it yet

Answer (score 8):

Can I plug my own tutorial, which covers the materials from the official Django tutorial, but uses full TDD all the way - including "proper" functional/acceptance tests using the Selenium browser-automation tool...  http://tdd-django-tutorial.com

[update 2014-01] I now have a book, just about to be published by OReilly, that covers all the stuff from the tutorial and much more.  The full thing is available online (free) at http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com

Comment: Attended a course based on Harry's tutorial at EuroPython this year - very comprehensive and well done.

Comment: I have went thru the online book - it is a great resource.  And Harry has been very responsive to reader's comments and suggestions.  Also there are videos of him presenting the material online if you prefer that method.

Comment: I am at chapter 20 of this book. Though it's my first go around with TDD, or any kind of development, really, I'd like to give it my full throated endorsement. It is very comprehensive - django, selenium, unittest, Jenkins, and TDD best practices. Whatever I end up doing from here on out is going to be a helluva lot better.

Answer (score 2):

I know that Kent Beck's book (which you mentioned) covers TDD in Python to some pretty good depth.  If I remember correctly, the last half of the book takes you through development of a unit test framework in Python.  There's nothing specific to web development, though, which is a problem in many TDD resources that I've read.  It's a best practice to keep your business logic separate from your presentation in order to make your BL more testable, among other reasons.

Another good book that you might want to look into is [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054).  It doesn't use Python, but it does talk a lot about designing for testability, how to use mocks and stubs (which you'll need for testing web applications), and automating testing.  It's more advanced than Beck's book, which makes it a good follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend "xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code" by Gerard Meszaros. It is not Python or Web specific, but it's a good book on TDD in general and the xUnit framework in particular. Since python unittest is actually an xUnit implementation ("a Python version of JUnit", as the docs say), I'd say that the book is very useful for Python unit testers.

It has an online version at [xunitpatterns.com](http://xunitpatterns.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.fruiapps.com/tag/test-driven-development) is a great series of article written on test driven development in python. It starts from basic and goes to a point, where you are taught stuffs as designing for maintainability etc. I am sure you would like it.

Answer (score 0):

A very good unit test framework is also [trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedTrial) from the twisted project.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game with this one, but I have been hunting for a Python oriented TDD book, and I just found [Python Testing: Beginner's Guide by Daniel Arbuckle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198848). Haven't had a chance to read it yet, but when I do, I'll try to remember to post a follow up here. The reviews on the Amazon page look pretty positive though.